# play videos from your computer on your Android, without copying them to your device

Tags: android, streaming, broadcast, multimedia, file-manager

http://www.howtogeek.com/120882/how-to-access-shared-windows-folders-and-stream-videos-over-wi-fi-on-android/

Look at this link. It has a demo in which they use ES File Explorer and play a video/movie directly on android device without copying.

So my simple question is,

**What protocol do they ( i.e ES File Explorer) use / how exactly they manage to stream or broadcast this video file on to android device ? Is there any specific protocol for this to perform ?  Can i do the same thing in an android app ?**

I've no idea in this so i had to start with very basic. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> What protocol do they ( i.e ES File Explorer) use

They appear to use SMB, based on the first screenshot.

> Is there any specific protocol for this to perform ?

[SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (also known as CIFS) is a protocol. It has been in use on Windows networks for a couple of decades.

> Can i do the same thing in an android app ?

I am not aware of any Android-specific libraries for this, though I know that some people have been trying [jCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/) for this. I do not know the details of how they get that to work for playing back videos. However, [this open source media player app](https://github.com/MizzleDK/Mizuu) uses jCIFS and, AFAIK, can play back videos using it.

Comment: Thank you very much. @CommonsWare